# Em dash next to displayed equation

Tags: punctuation, mathematics, dashes, em-dashes

I want to use an em dash to set off a parenthetical text for emphasis. However, the text in question is adjacent to a displayed mathematical formula.

What is the proper way to do so?

I am aware that mathematics should always be punctuated to achieve correct grammar in the sentence. However, in this case there are two valid possibilities (as an example, see attached picture) and I do not know which one to choose.

I have checked the Chicago Manual of Style and I could not find any answer.

EDIT: I am not seeking advice on how to rephrase the particular sentence in the picture. My question is more general. Namely, assuming one wants to use em dashes next to a displayed mathematical object, where should the em dash be placed?

[image]

Comment: Don't put a dash next to a formula; that is guaranteed to confuse people. (1) looks ok to me, but you could always rewrite to avoid the initial dash (it would often be possible to put a condition such as c not being equal to 0 on the line with the equation, rather than expressing it in text).

Comment: Hence the following equation holds:    {new ....................................... line ......................................... needed}                                                                   
                                                                    a = b + c  (c ≠ 0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mathematical formatting is a matter for Mathematics.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, that question could possibly be on-topic on Math SE, but that doesn’t mean it’s off-topic here. This deals with English punctuation rules (albeit in a special context), which is clearly on-topic here. You could replace the mathematical equation with a chemical one or a linguistic diagram, and the question still holds. It is not about mathematical typesetting at all. Also, my answer argues purely from the language perspective; mathematics doesn’t enter it.

Comment: (Part 1.) I have heard lectures along these lines on writing a mathematics paper. The sentence including the equation should make sense in the reader's mind. (The lecturer, J.L. Bentley, encouraged us to read the paper out loud, and substituted a grunt for the equation.) (Part 2.) I might rewrite this "Hence equation (16) holds, {----new line----} a = b + c  (16) {----new line----} where c is nonzero." (Part 3.) The use of equation numbers depends on the style guide of the publication you are writing for.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I could not disagree more. The question is not about math formatting at all. It is about punctuation in presence of a displayed mathematical equation. This is a topic which is covered by any style guide.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also, I was not seeking advice on how to rephrase the particular sentence I included as an example.

Comment: @ Wrzlprmft 'English punctuation' is used in chemical nomenclature and in passwords, but these are not everyday standard English usages. One belongs in the field of chemistry, the other in the field of cryptography.  Similarly, equations and their formatting / embedding belong in the field of mathematics (/ possibly physics etc).  Not all that is English-language–based fits the intended ELU model.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I am not aware of any rule (or similar) that this site is limited to “everyday standard English usages”. If it were, a considerable amount of questions would need to be closed for violating that, including many in the tag [tag:mathematics]. Also, my point is that the answer does not depend on whether this is a mathematical, physical, or chemical equation, and expertise of those fields is not the most relevant thing here. On the other hand, if we go to a language with a different punctuation paradigm, we have to expect the answer to change.

Comment: General advice on mathematical notation: Look at mathematical text that you consider to be well-written and imitate that.  Do not ask specialists in English how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation such as periods, commas, and occasionally question marks are usually put after display equations (your *a* = *b* + *c*), because they are are a part of the sentence (or part thereof) that ends with the equation. By contrast, your dash belongs to what follows the equation and thus it logically belongs there, i.e., your Option 1.

That being said, I fail to imagine a situation where starting a parenthesis (of any kind) after an equation is a good idea. This only happens if you have to have a thought and grammar that spans an equation and a parenthesis. One of those usually is too much already; two almost certainly are. For example, in your sentence, I won’t know what you actually want to tell me until the very last word (*holds*). What I actually did when first reading it was to scan ahead after *equation* to find the missing verb and only afterwards did I look at the equation and the parenthesis. So, the sentence is not in the order in which your reader actually wants to read it – that’s bad. If your sentence is more complex, the reader probably has to read it several times to find out what is going on.

Instead write something like:

> Hence the following equation holds:
>                     *a* = *b* + *c,*
> where *c* must be nonzero.

Comment: Add supporting reference from a general English style guide (and supporting references _are_ a virtual necessity on ELU) and I'll concede that '[this] question could possibly be on-topic ... here'.